# Calculating energy accumulated in toroidal coil

Tags: electromagnetism, coil

[image: Cross section]

That's a cross section of said coil. My question, is since there are two different permeabilities, can I split it into two toroidal coils, with unique permeabilities, or should I've done the Ampere's law for the middle, which I see now is at 25mm, μ2. Tangential vectors of the strength of the magnetic fields are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two cores are effectively in parallel (like resistors). So, calculate the net [reluctance](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=magnetic+reluctance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=eXASVY2zAaSu7gbcgoDoDg) based on this formula for each part of the core: -

\$R = \dfrac{l}{\mu\cdot A}\$

Where l is length of the magnetic path, A is cross sectional area and mu is permeability of material.

Calculate the composite reluctance and use that figure noting that reluctance = \$\dfrac{mmf}{\Phi}\$ etc..

mmf is ampere turns and phi is flux.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, that would work. But I did it by splitting it on an exam, so any chance my way could work? Is splitting it into two coils, with same dimensions and radius, a possible solution?

Comment: I guess if you calculate using both methods and they agree numerically then your exam method is fine (or you got lucky with the numbers).